# SOLR performance

Tags: solr, jetty, solrj

I am using SolrJ + Solr in my project.
The problem is that I faced unclear bottleneck regarding Solr/Jetty

Using jvisualvm I connected to JVM instance under which Solr launched and saw that 77% of time spent in method "org.eclipse.jetty.io.ByteArrayBuffer.readFrom()", stacktrace of one of threads is below:

```
"qtp64700533-36718" - Thread t@36718
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ByteArrayBuffer.readFrom(ByteArrayBuffer.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.bio.StreamEndPoint.fill(StreamEndPoint.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.fill(SocketConnector.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.fill(HttpParser.java:1040)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So, it may looks OK that time spent on I/O, but:

1. application, which doing query launched on local machine (so I/O time should not be big, and thread state "RUNNABLE" in above stacktrace seems suspicious)
2. query response times may have up to 5-10 seconds
3. Load average on machine (CentOS) is about 10

Any help/advices appreciated, thanks!

UPD:
Indeed, guys, I forgot to give addtional info. Here it is:

**hardware**: i3770, 32gb ram, according to iotop it shows 50-600kb/sec read, 200-1000kb/sec write (almost most relates to SOLR process)
**OS**: Centos 6.6
**java**: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (1.7.0_71 24.65-b04)
**solr**: 4.9.0 (launched with -Xmx=24000, but I think should split SOLR cores to separare JVM SOLR instances to minimize GC time)
**solrj**: 4.10.3, adding/updating/removing documents done with commitWithIn=10000 msec in java code.

about schemas: I am storing in SOLR data (ads + objects) regarding 5 countries: UA, RU, PL, BY, KZ.
So, there are 2 cores for each country, for example for Ukraine: ua_ads and ua_objects (10 cores in total)
Schemas between countries almost indentical, see below for Ukraine

"ua_ads" schema (should rename it from "example" though :) )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="example" version="1.5">
  <fieldType name="int"       class="solr.TrieIntField"   precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
  <fieldType name="long"      class="solr.TrieLongField"  precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
  <fieldType name="boolean"   class="solr.BoolField"      sortMissingLast="true"/>
  <fieldType name="tdate"     class="solr.TrieDateField"  precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
  <fieldType name="string"    class="solr.StrField"       sortMissingLast="true" />
  <fieldType name="text_ru"   class="solr.TextField"      positionIncrementGap="100"/>

  <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

  <uniqueKey>adId</uniqueKey>

  <field name="adId"          type="long"     indexed="true"    stored="true"   required="true"/>
  <field name="objectId"      type="long"     indexed="true"    stored="true"   required="false"/>
  <field name="url"           type="string"   indexed="false"   stored="true"   required="true"/>
  <field name="regionId"      type="int"      indexed="false"   stored="true"   required="true"/>
  <field name="sourceId"      type="int"      indexed="false"   stored="true"   required="true"/>
  <field name="type"          type="int"      indexed="false"   stored="true"   required="true"/>
  <field name="title"         type="text_ru"  indexed="false"   stored="true"   required="true"/>
  <field name="address"       type="text_ru"  indexed="false"   stored="true"   required="true"/>
  <field name="text"          type="text_ru"  indexed="false"   stored="true"   required="true"/>
  <field name="dateFound"     type="tdate"    indexed="true"    stored="true"   required="true"/>
  <!-- should be a string field (not int) to avoid cutting zero at beginning of phone number -->
  <field name="phoneNumbers"  type="string"   indexed="true"    stored="true"   required="true"   multiValued="true"/>
  <field name="priceLocal"    type="long"     indexed="false"   stored="true"   required="false"/>
  <field name="priceUsd"      type="long"     indexed="false"   stored="true"   required="false"/>
  <field name="currency"      type="int"      indexed="false"   stored="true"   required="false"/>

  <field name="roomsCount"    type="int"      indexed="false"   stored="true"   required="false"/>
  <field name="area"          type="int"      indexed="false"   stored="true"   required="false"/>
  <field name="imagesCount"   type="int"      indexed="true"    stored="true"   required="true"/>
</schema>
```

"ua_objects" schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="example" version="1.5">

  <fieldType name="int"     class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
  <fieldType name="long"    class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
  <fieldType name="float"   class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
  <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
  <fieldType name="tdate"   class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
  <fieldType name="string"  class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />
  <fieldtype name="binary"  class="solr.BinaryField"/>

  <fieldType name="addr_ru" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <!-- no stemming for address, dots must me followed by space: "г. Киев" -->
      <!-- char filters is always firs (preprocessing) -->
      <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="lang/chars_replacement.txt" />
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <!-- replacing all except letters, removing "-" in home address (9-А) -->
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="[^0-9abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяіїє\-]" replacement="" replace="all"/>
      <!-- replacing all except letters, removing "-" in home address ("9-а" => "9а") -->
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(\d{1,3})[\- ]([абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщ])" replacement="$1$2" replace="all"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="lang/cities_ukr2rus.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="ї" replacement="и" replace="all"/>
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="і" replacement="и" replace="all"/>
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="й" replacement="и" replace="all"/>
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="ё" replacement="е" replace="all"/>
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="є" replacement="е" replace="all"/>
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="э" replacement="е" replace="all"/>
      <!-- 1-length is for case with home letters: "Хрещатик, 3" -->
      <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="1" max="64"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_ru.txt,lang/stopwords_addr.txt" format="snowball"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_ru" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <!-- dots must me followed by space: "г. Киев" -->
      <!-- char filters is always firs (preprocessing) -->
      <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="lang/chars_replacement.txt" />
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="[^0-9abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяіїє\-]" replacement="" replace="all"/>
      <!-- replacing all except letters, removing "-" in home address ("9-а" => "9а") -->
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(\d{1,3})[\- ]([абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщ])" replacement="$1$2" replace="all"/>
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="ї" replacement="и" replace="all"/>
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="і" replacement="и" replace="all"/>
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="й" replacement="и" replace="all"/>
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="ё" replacement="е" replace="all"/>
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="є" replacement="е" replace="all"/>
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="э" replacement="е" replace="all"/>
      <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="1" max="64"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_ru.txt" format="snowball"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="lang/synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Russian"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>

  <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

  <uniqueKey>objectId</uniqueKey>

  <field name="objectId"      type="long"     indexed="true"    stored="true"   required="true"/>
  <field name="url"           type="string"   indexed="false"   stored="true"   required="true"/>
  <field name="regionId"      type="int"      indexed="true"    stored="true"   required="true"/>
  <field name="sourceId"      type="int"      indexed="false"   stored="true"   required="true"/>
  <field name="type"          type="int"      indexed="true"    stored="true"   required="true"/>
  <field name="address"       type="addr_ru"  indexed="true"    stored="true"   required="true"/>
  <field name="title"         type="text_ru"  indexed="true"    stored="true"   required="true"/>
  <field name="text"          type="text_ru"  indexed="true"    stored="true"   required="true"/>
  <field name="dateFound"     type="tdate"    indexed="true"    stored="true"   required="true"/>
  <!-- should be a string field (not int) to avoid cutting zero at beginning of phone number -->
  <field name="phoneNumbers"  type="string"   indexed="true"    stored="true"   required="true"   multiValued="true"/>
  <field name="ownerDetected" type="boolean"  indexed="true"    stored="true"   required="true"/>
  <field name="priceUsd"      type="long"     indexed="true"    stored="true"   required="false"/>
  <field name="priceLocal"    type="long"     indexed="false"   stored="true"   required="false"/>
  <field name="currency"      type="int"      indexed="false"   stored="true"   required="false"/>
  <field name="roomsCount"    type="int"      indexed="true"    stored="true"   required="false"/>
  <field name="area"          type="int"      indexed="true"    stored="true"   required="false"/>

  <field name="dateUpdated"   type="tdate"    indexed="true"    stored="true"   required="true"/>
  <field name="dateClosed"    type="tdate"    indexed="true"    stored="true"   required="false"/>
  <field name="m2priceRel"    type="float"    indexed="true"    stored="true"   required="false"/>
  <field name="ceddData"      type="binary"   indexed="false"   stored="true"   required="false"  multiValued="true"/>
  <field name="imagesCount"   type="int"      indexed="true"    stored="true"   required="true"/>
  <field name="uniqAdTexts"   type="string"   indexed="false"   stored="true"   required="true"   multiValued="true"/>
</schema>
```

biggest indexes:
ru_ads: 2.99gb
ru_objects: 3.25gb
ua_ads: 5.45gb
ua_objects: 2.36gb
other cores indexes relatively small

queries which runs too long ("too long" from client-side) looks like this one (took from SOLR log, "????" is just non-english letters)

```
400723188 [qtp64700533-40547] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  ? [ua-objects] webapp=/solr path=/select params={mm=2&fl=*&start=0&q=(??????\+????????\+???????\+????????)+AND+type:3+AND+regionId:2+AND+((*:*+AND+-roomsCount:[*+TO+*])+OR+roomsCount:[2+TO+2])+AND+((*:*+AND+-area:[*+TO+*])+OR+area:[40+TO+60])+AND+((*:*+AND+-priceUsd:[*+TO+*])+OR+priceUsd:[23500+TO+70500])+AND+dateUpdated:[2014-12-09T10:23:07Z+TO+2015-01-28T10:23:07Z]+AND+-objectId:(27824841)&qf=address^20+title^2&wt=javabin&version=2&defType=edismax&rows=2147483647} hits=18 status=0 QTime=287

401989528 [qtp64700533-40830] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  ? [ru-objects] webapp=/solr path=/select params={mm=2&fl=*&start=0&q=(?????????????\+??????)+AND+type:4+AND+regionId:162+AND+((*:*+AND+-roomsCount:[*+TO+*])+OR+roomsCount:[1+TO+1])+AND+((*:*+AND+-area:[*+TO+*])+OR+area:[40+TO+58])+AND+((*:*+AND+-priceUsd:[*+TO+*])+OR+priceUsd:[9+TO+27])+AND+dateUpdated:[2014-12-09T10:44:08Z+TO+2015-01-28T10:44:08Z]+AND+-objectId:(26415616)&qf=address^20+title^2&wt=javabin&version=2&defType=edismax&rows=2147483647} hits=820 status=0 QTime=5755

400832723 [qtp64700533-40322] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  ? [ru-objects] webapp=/solr path=/select params={mm=2&fl=*&start=0&q=(????????\+???????)+AND+type:4+AND+regionId:102+AND+((*:*+AND+-roomsCount:[*+TO+*])+OR+roomsCount:[1+TO+1])+AND+((*:*+AND+-area:[*+TO+*])+OR+area:[31+TO+45])+AND+((*:*+AND+-priceUsd:[*+TO+*])+OR+priceUsd:[115+TO+343])+AND+dateUpdated:[2014-12-09T10:24:57Z+TO+2015-01-28T10:24:57Z]+AND+-objectId:(26415342)&qf=address^20+title^2&wt=javabin&version=2&defType=edismax&rows=2147483647} hits=9 status=0 QTime=372

402069370 [qtp64700533-40832] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  ? [ru-objects] webapp=/solr path=/select params={mm=1&fl=*&start=0&q=(????????\+?????????\+??\+????????)+AND+type:3+AND+regionId:135+AND+((*:*+AND+-roomsCount:[*+TO+*])+OR+roomsCount:[1+TO+1])+AND+((*:*+AND+-area:[*+TO+*])+OR+area:[28+TO+40])+AND+((*:*+AND+-priceUsd:[*+TO+*])+OR+priceUsd:[9529+TO+28585])+AND+dateUpdated:[2014-10-30T10:45:33Z+TO+2015-01-28T10:45:33Z]+AND+-objectId:(26415855)&qf=address^20+title^2+text&wt=javabin&version=2&defType=edismax&rows=2147483647} hits=14075 status=0 QTime=544

401805198 [qtp64700533-40233] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  ? [ua-objects] webapp=/solr path=/select params={mm=2&fl=*&start=0&q=(??????\+??\+??????\+?????\+??????????)+AND+type:3+AND+regionId:16+AND+((*:*+AND+-roomsCount:[*+TO+*])+OR+roomsCount:[3+TO+3])+AND+((*:*+AND+-area:[*+TO+*])+OR+area:[93+TO+95])+AND+((*:*+AND+-priceUsd:[*+TO+*])+OR+priceUsd:[284050+TO+313950])+AND+dateUpdated:[2015-01-08T10:41:09Z+TO+2015-01-28T10:41:09Z]+AND+-objectId:(27826334)&qf=address^20+title^2&wt=javabin&version=2&defType=edismax&rows=2147483647} hits=6 status=0 QTime=462
```

here is fresh profiling screenshot from jvisualvm
[image: screenshot form jvisualvm]

part of "top" command, delay=10sec
[image: top output]

Comment: plz share more info about your installation, how you run Solr, etc. It could be a lot of stuff wrong. How big your index is?

Comment: In addition, how is your schema and which queries do you run?

Comment: Mysterion, cheffe - I added additional info

Comment: Am I seeing right that you try to fetch a full hitset, each time? I can see the parameter `rows=2147483647`. Then it is no wonder that queries may take some time. Solr does render output for 820 results in your second query

Comment: cheffe, that's right, I am setting rows=214748364 (max integer) to fetch all possible results that match query. This is definitely not best practice, however, I was expecting to see "hot" method somewhere in "CPU" method, not in "ByteArrayBuffer.readFrom()" which is looks like "I/O" method (added "top" command output)

Comment: Well, get rid of this. This is just useless ... why are you doing it? I bet there are other means to get that done.

Comment: well, I just need all queries that match criteria. I am doing additional checks in java code (comparing how texts are similar, etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have given the parameter `rows=2147483647` in every of your queries. The meaning of this parameter is (taken from the reference)

> You can use the rows parameter to paginate results from a query. The
>   parameter specifies the maximum number of documents from the complete
>   result set that Solr should return to the client at one time.
>
> The default value is 10. That is, by default, Solr returns 10
>   documents at a time in response to a query.

So you are telling Solr in effect to send all hits found for a query in a single response. This is the reason for your bad performance.

Does google send you all 500.000.000 hits found [when querying for "java"](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=java), no. Why not, performance. Each and every IR application I know gives you a small page with the first results so that a search performs well.

This is the reason for your high I/O, solr fetches the records from the disk and writes them to the response. This is I/O, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: cheffe, this may be true (take into account that I do not need pagination, this result never showed to user and used in analytic).

Comment: When doing analytics, use Solr's Faceting and Pivot Facets, incredible fast and powerful. Do not make the mistake to implement statistics on your own, when using Solr.

Comment: some more thoughs than: 1) sometimes query takes 5-10 seconds, which is quite big time for accessing records on HDD, right ?  2) As I said above read is 200-500kb per second by SOLR, so this looks like not a "heavy" diks access. 3) Caching (by OS) should also take place...

Comment: "Solr's Faceting and Pivot Facets" - thanks, will dig into it

Comment: cheffe, thanks, I accepted your answer. How do you think - changing HDD to SSD without replacing functionality will decrease response time or not ? According to stats I gathered solr also heavily uses CPU.

Comment: This will increase your performance for queries that hit uncached regions and in case a user performs deep caching. When the first x documents that are found are cached, this is related to RAM and CPU. SSDs are never a bad thing :)

Comment: Solr IO is primarily a lot of random seeks, so KB/sec is a poor measurement of disk activity. And yes, SSDs helps a lot there.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using this for analytics and want to extract everything matching, you should look into the new [streaming export](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Exporting+Result+Sets) feature. Unfortunately, it is only available in Solr 4.10.

You can also update to SSD - it is very good boost for Solr performance.

Finally, review your cache levels. If you don't update frequently and some of the caches are full, you could increase the defaults. If you do update frequently, it's not as beneficial as caches are invalidated on commits.